# Thymeleaf: literals and variables in a HTML id

Tags: html, thymeleaf

I have this piece of code in Thymeleaf:

```
<tr th:each="image: ${images}" >

   <img id="|'idAwesomeIcon${image.id}'|" .. />

</tr>
```

also I tried

```
<tr th:each="image: ${images}" >

   <img id=“idAwesomeIcon|${image.id}|" .. />

</tr>
```

also I tried

```
<tr th:each="image: ${images}" >

   <img id="\'idAwesomeIcon' + ${image.id} +'\'" .. />

</tr>
```

expecting the id to be replace with something like `idAwesomeIcon666` but when I see the source code of the HTML page there is no such a substitution and I can still see `${image.id}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use th:id attribute if you want to dynamically populate values

```
<img th:id=“'idAwesomeIcon'+${image.id}" .. />
```